# Behavior of mutation on multiple fetches of same entity in persistence context

Tags: hibernate, jpa

```
private Thing fetchThing(Long id, Owner owner) {
  return em.createQuery("SELECT t FROM Thing t WHERE t.id = :id AND t.owner = :owner")
           .setParameter("id", id)
           .setParameter("owner", owner)
           .getSingleResult();
}

/* Transactional, CMT */
public void mutateThing() {
  var thing1 = fetchThing(123L, myOwner);
  var thing2 = fetchThing(123L, myOwner);

  thing1.setColor("blue");
}
```

1. Is `thing1` guaranteed by spec to be the same instance as `thing2`?
2. If not, is the mutation on `thing1` guaranteed to be synchronized?

   - How would conflicting mutations on `thing1` and `thing2` be resolved?

Answer (score 0):

As the queries run inside the same transaction and the JPA persistence context is bound to the transaction you will get the same entity instance from the persistence context.

Comment: Thank you! So no matter what query produces an entity, once an instance is in the persistence context, any query that results in that record in the DB will return that exact Java object (matched by the `@Id` field). Is that correct?

Comment: Exactly. This can also be a bad thing if some one else changes the entity in the database